# doctrine2-spatial how to use multilinestring type

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using Symfony 4 and [Doctrine2-Spatial](https://github.com/creof/doctrine2-spatial). The documentation [configuration guide](https://github.com/creof/doctrine2-spatial/blob/master/doc/configuration.md) says:

> Add the types and functions you need to your Symfony configuration file. The doctrine type names are not hardcoded."

And there is an example:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    types:
        geometry:   CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\GeometryType
        point:      CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\Geometry\PointType
        polygon:    CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\Geometry\PolygonType
        linestring: CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\Geometry\LineStringType
```

I need to use **MultiLineString** type, but there is no such type class in `CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\Geometry\` directory. I've added **MultiLineStringType** (copy of **LineStringType** class) to my `App\Doctrine` directory and added a line to doctrine config like this:

```
multilinestring: App\Doctrine\MultiLineStringType
```

Then in my controller I do the following:

```
$parser = new \CrEOF\Geo\WKT\Parser($multilinestring);
$geo = $parser->parse();
$path = new \CrEOF\Spatial\PHP\Types\Geometry\MultiLineString($geo['value']);
$route->setPath($path); // The multilinestring field type
```

But then when I persist my doctrine entity, I got an exception

> Geometry column values must implement GeometryInterface

Please help me. What am I doing wrong? The documentation is very poor...

**UPD:** If I put multilinestring data by native SQL query like this:

```
UPDATE Routes SET Path=PolyFromText(MULTILINESTRING (....)) WHERE Id=1
```

and then get data via ORM `$entity->getPath()` I got a normal `CrEOF\Spatial\PHP\Types\Geometry\MultiLineString` object. So I guess the problem is in my Controller where I trying to set MultiLineString object.

Answer (score 0):

You may just change:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            geometry:   CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\GeometryType
            point:      CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\Geometry\PointType
            polygon:    CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\Geometry\PolygonType
            linestring: CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\Geometry\LineStringType
```

into this:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            geometry:        CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\GeometryType
            point:           CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\Geometry\PointType
            polygon:         CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\Geometry\PolygonType
            linestring:      CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\Geometry\LineStringType
            multilinestring: CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\Geometry\MultiLineStringType
```

Comment: There is no class MultiLineStringType in folder CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\Geometry

Comment: Does your own `MultiLineStringType` extend CrEOF's `GeometryType` ?

Comment: Yes, sure. There is the code:

namespace App\Doctrine;
use CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\GeometryType;

class MultiLineStringType extends GeometryType
{

}